# Code that's inside a for loop and written after the std::accumulate will not execute

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want to write a function calculating the sum of each row of a 2d vector and find the maximum of those sums. I tried to loop through the vector and use std::accumulate to sum up each sub-vector. However, each time the loop increment, the code after the std::accumulate will not execute. For example, in the following code, after assigning the sum of the first row of the 2d vector to the temp variable, the mx value will not change not matter if the condition [(firstSum < temp) ? temp : firstSum] is true or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <map>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int mx; int temp;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_2d_vector{
        {-10, 0, -1}, {1, 2, 4}, {4, 1, -1}, {6, 8, -10, -9}, {-1}};
    int firstSum = std::accumulate(my_2d_vector[0].begin(), 
    my_2d_vector[0].end(), 0);

    for (auto x: my_2d_vector)
        //mx will not be assigned and it will remain a value of 0.
        temp = std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0);
        mx = (firstSum < temp) ? temp : firstSum;
```

Can anybody help me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: The first call to `std::accumulate()` shouldn't compile, as `my_2d_vector` hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: I wrote that piece of code wrong. Sorry. I did initialize the vector first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop needs braces `{ ... }` around the body.

```
for (auto x: my_2d_vector) {
    //mx will not be assigned and it will remain a value of 0.
    temp = std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0);
    mx = (firstSum < temp) ? temp : firstSum;
}
```

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you. So the braces must be there?

Comment: Without them, only the first statement is considered to be inside the loop. C++ doesn't care about indentation like some languages do, and many folks (myself included) recommend simply placing them as a rule, to prevent confusion like this.